# Getting a foreach to run once

Tags: c#, xml, foreach

So the question is this, I have a for each loop that I am currently using to retrieve data from a query of an XML file which then gets put into a string; like so:

```
foreach (var value in dateQuery)
                date = value.Element("HistoryCreation").Value;
```

I know for a fact (Based on the way the xml file stores values and the query being used) that there will only be one value in dateQuery.

Thus, I would like to know (for the purposes of making my program more efficient and learning how to code better), is there a better way to do this or are foreach's the only way?

Comment: I can't believe it took so long (3 minutes) to answer this question.

Comment: It takes a minute for questions to show up sometimes.  Especially on the front page (not when you click "Questions")

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could use:

```
dateQuery.First().Element("HistoryCreation").Value
```

This won't fail if there is multiple items in the query.   If you want it to fail if there are multiple items, then use Single

Answer (score 8):

```
date = dateQuery.Single().Element("HistoryCreation").Value;
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are using .NET 3.5 or newer you could use the extension method `Enumerable.Single`:

```
var value = dateQuery.Single();
date = value.Element("HistoryCreation").Value;
```

Then if your assumption 'there will only be one value in dateQuery' is wrong it will throw an exception.

Comment: tster: I removed it - it's clear he's using 3.5 from the use of var.

Answer (score 5):

Mark's Answer is by far the best, but I put mine for illustrating foreach loop.

```
foreach (var value in dateQuery) {
    date = value.Element("HistoryCreation").Value;
    break;  // break current loop
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Emmanual, if you know you only need to do something once, you shouldn't use a loop.

Answer (score 4):

Summing up:

- use First() if you want the first item and know that there is at least one (or more) items in the sequence.
- use FirstOrDefault() if the sequence can have any number of items
- use Single() if the sequence can have exactly one item
- use SingleOrDefault() if the sequence always has either zero or one item

Note that there are also versions of these which take predicates, so that you can abbreviate

```
var result = sequence.Where(predicate).First();
```

to

```
var result = sequence.First(predicate);
```

Answer (score 2):

Can't you simply access the first index of `dateQuery`?

```
date = dateQuery[0].Element("HistoryCreation").Value;
```

Comment: @tster - Agreed, but that is not implied in the question.

Comment: You'd need to check that dateQuery has at least one element otherwise you'll get an index out of range exception.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Enumerable.Single](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155325.aspx) or [Enumerable.SingleOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451.aspx):

```
 date = dateQuery.Single().Element("HistoryCreation").Value;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
dateQuery.First().Element("HistoryCreation").Value
```

if you are able to use LINQ

Comment: damn, you really need to be quick on the draw here!

Comment: I agree, these answers were all right; and they came so fast. :/

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
var theValue = dateQuery.FirstOrDefault();
if (theValue != null)
{
   data = theValue.Element("HistoryCreation").Value;
}
else
{
       //Deal with the fact that there is no data
}
```

You could use .First() or .Single(), but if there is nothing in dataQuery an exception will be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

that should do the trick:

```
using System.Linq;

dateQuery.Single();
```